# Angular : the AOT compiler duplicates my styles

Tags: angular, webpack

Here is my configuration :

main.ts :

```
import "./vendor";
```

vendor.ts :

```
(...)
import "./styles/styles.css";
```

angular-cli.json :

```
(...)
  "apps": [
    {
     (...)
      "styles": [ "./styles/styles.css" ],
      (...)
    }
  ]
```

With this configuration, all run correctly with the webpack-dev-server.

But, when I compile my projet with this command :

```
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
```

I get two strictly identical CSS files, they are both included in index.html.
[image]

If I remove styles.css from .angular-cli.json, there is no file at all.

Where is my mistake ?
Thanks

Comment: Remove style.css form your angular-cli.json and i think webpack will add your style as <style> tag in your html. please check it.

Comment: If I remove styles.css from .angular-cli.json, there is no file at all.

Comment: Yes you will find no file because it's embedded in your index.html

Comment: I just tried what you propose but there is no embedded style in index.htm. There is only .js files and index.html without <style> of <link>

Comment: Sorry for that, i meant remove it from the vendor not from the angular-cli.json.

Comment: Yes but if I do that the webpack-dev-server not work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164683/discussion-between-nour-and-a-baudouin).

Comment: I finally found the solution : I remove import .css from vendor.ts and add styles.css in webpack.config entry.vendor

Comment: Glad it works finally

Comment: @A.Baudouin So you can place your answer, for others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

1. Remove `import "./styles/styles.css"` from vendor.ts
2. Modify webpack.config.js like this :

   ```
   module.exports = {
     entry: {(...)
      "vendor": [
        './vendor.ts',
        './styles/styles.css'
        ](...)
   ```
3. Leave `"styles": [ "./styles/styles.css" ]` in angular-cli.json

With this configuration webpack-dev-server and AOT compiler work properly.